# How does the 'Souls' mode work in Move or Die?

Tags: move-or-die

I've played it a couple of times and I tend to just die pretty much straight away. There isn't any description given of what you're supposed to do other than gather souls, and I cannot find anything on google. Can anyone explain this game mode?

Answer (score 2):

Every couple of seconds someone will be killed. When you die you can still move around and your soul is released from your body as a little light of your color. You can come back to life by picking up your or any other player's soul. Alive player can also take those souls and will release them all upon death. The player who finish the game with the more souls wins.